# How can I run a method from my view, and have it return to the sending page, which requires a Category ID based querystring it's not sent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

As a pre-note I've recently moved to MVC under .net, and as such some terminology may be a bit off, & I've tried to remove irrelevant pieces of code where I can.

In the web application, from my View I have a loop that outputs items passed from a view model. A view model is populated by **Items** for a particular **category** and the category ID is sent through a query-string

```
@model Web.Models.ItemViewModel

[html only - removed for brevity]

@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
     <tr>
          <td>@item.Name</td>
          <td><a href="@Url.Action("/DeleteItem", new {id = item.ID})">remove</a></td>
     </tr>
}
```

In my controller I've got a method for Index and DeleteItem as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid categoryID, Type categoryType)
{
    // populate items
    return View(new ItemViewModel
    {
        // maps items
    )};
}

public ActionResult DeleteItem(Guid id)
{
    ItemService.Delete(id);
    return View("Index");
}
```

When the DeleteItem method completes it returns to the Index, though as there is no querystring, I receive a blank page - or an error page, stating that the Category ID is unset. An ideal "Index" string would look like

```
www.domain.com/Items/ItemCategory?id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&Type=MyCategoryType
```

I've attempted various different approaches to no success including:

- returning to a URI Referrer, which ends up attempting to return the Delete Page itself (which doesn't exist)
- before deleting the item, grabbing it's Category ID, and Category Type - this worked, however an individual item can belong to more than one category and category Type, so it's an unreliable approach - as it could end up sending the end user from Category (A) to Category (B) and a whole different view.
- passing the relevant data to the Delete method eg:

  ```
   public ActionResult DeleteItem (Guid id, Guid SendingCategoryID, ItemType SendingCategoryItemType)
  ```

which 1) seems like I'm passing a lot of unnecessary data - some of which isn't immediately available without a DB call, and 2) within the application's lifetime will become completely unmaintainable. An item can belong to more than one Category or Category Type, and further one Category can belong to more than one Category Type. I can't even imagine how difficult debugging an issue with this technique would be.

My next approach was to call the method without leaving the page. I'm completely unsure of how to do that though, any help or suggestions even in how to word my issue to get a decent result out of Google with which I can continue researching would be very helpful and appreciated.

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion in your case passing the category (or even a more general return location argument of some form) is perfectly valid. Of course you can do the delete via AJAX and not leave the page but the additional argument should not be your reason to do this.

I assume that you use RedirectToAction if you have the additional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing the `Index` view without the necessary data you probably want to redirect to the `Index` action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteItem(Guid id)
{
    ItemService.Delete(id);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Also, please make sure that `DeleteItem` is only executed with an HTTP POST request. Changing data should only happen on a POST request. That also means the delete link in your Index page will need to become a form that does the POST.